# Is it Possible to Increase Display Resolution for OS X Maverick

Tags: mac, operating-systems, resolution, display-settings, osx-mavericks

The new OS X Maverick operating system has reduced maximum display resolution from 1920 x 1200 in Mountain Lion to 1680 x 1050, which is a SIZABLE reduction. The difference is obvious when viewing videos or photos. In addition, the colors are less vibrant.  Does anyone know a way to change the display resolution for Maverick, thus restoring Mountain Lion resolution (1920 x 1200)...along with color vibrancy.  By the way, I am using a 2012 Macbook Pro, with Matte display, which I think makes matters worse. At 1920 x 1200 my Macbook Pro was excellent...but at 1680 x 1050, it is very pedestrian.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with mine, so I contacted apple support. when you are in System Preferences>Displays - hold the option key while clicking on scaled, all the resolutions will appear again. I hope this helps!

Comment: This worked great for me.  I had to hold the option key to have the 'Detect Display' button show up.  I clicked that button and things were back to normal.  Not thrilled of the secret hidden useful buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my 3840x1024 Matrox TripleHead2Go display. After upgrading to Mavericks, it detected the display as 1280x1024 with no option in Display Preference to select my previous resolution.

I solved the problem by installing "[SwitchResX](https://www.macupdate.com/app/iphone/8355/switchresx)" which allows me to manually define customised resolution for each display.